# How to check file type in kendo file upload using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, kendo-ui

I have kendo file upload with AngularJs which is working good for upload, Another requirement is Document Category is dropdown (Excel,Pdf,Word). Lets assume if user select excel from dropdown how can i restrict user to select only excel file by using onSelect method ?

So far tried code below...

main.html

```
<form name="addRiskForm" novalidate class="border-box-sizing">
        <div class="modalForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label for="docCate" class="col-md-4">Document Category:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                       <select
                            kendo-drop-down-list
                            data-text-field="'text'"
                            data-value-field="'id'" name="attchCategory"
                            k-option-label="'Select'"
                            ng-model="attchCategory"
                            k-data-source="docCategoryOptions"
                            id="docCate">
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
               <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldHeight">
                    <label for="issueNo" class="col-md-4">File name:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <input name="file"
                            type="file"
                            kendo-upload="fileAttachment"
                            k-upload="addMorePostParameters"
                            k-success="onSuccess"
                            k-error = "onError"
                            k-multiple="true"
                            k-options="fileAttachmentOptions"
                            k-select="onSelect"
                            />
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Ctrl.js

```
 $scope.fileAttachmentOptions = assessmentDocConfig.fileAttachmentConfig;
    $scope.docCategoryOptions = kendoCustomDataSource.getDropDownDataSource('RA_ATACH_TYP');
      $scope.$on('addDocument', function (s,id){
        $scope.riskAssessmentDTO.riskAssessmentKey = id;
        $scope.viewDocumentWin.open().center();
      });
      $scope.addMorePostParameters = function (e) {
        if (!$scope.attchCategory) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (!$scope.attchDesc) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.data = {
                attchCategory:$scope.attchCategory,
                attchDesc: $scope.attchDesc,
                riskAssessmentKey: $stateParams.assessmentId,
            };
        }
    };

    $scope.onSuccess = function () {
      $log.info('Upload Successfull...');
      $scope.attchCategory = '';
      $scope.attchDesc = '';
      var filesToBeRemoved = $scope.fileAttachment.wrapper.find('.k-file');
      $scope.fileAttachment._removeFileEntry(filesToBeRemoved);
      console.log('Attachment Successfully Saved');
      $scope.viewDocumentWin.close();
    };
    $scope.onSelect = function (e) {
      $.each(e.file, function (index, value) {
          var ok = value.extension == ".xlsx"
                   || value.extension == ".pdf"
                   || value.extension == ".doc"
                   || value.extension == ".html";

          if (value.extension === ok) {
              e.preventDefault();
              alert("Please upload jpg image files");
          }
      });
  };
    $scope.onError = function () {
      $log.info('Upload Errored out...');
      console.log('Error while uploading attachment');
    };
```

config.js

```
fileAttachmentConfig: {
  async: {
      saveUrl: 'app/upload/uploadAttch',
      removeUrl: 'remove',
      removeVerb: 'DELETE',
      autoUpload: false
  },
  template: '<span class=\'file-name-heading\'>Name:</span> <span>#=name#</span><button type=\'button\' class=\'k-upload-action\'></button>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `validation.allowedExtensions` property, for example:

**config.js**

```
fileAttachmentConfig: {
  async: {
      saveUrl: 'app/upload/uploadAttch',
      removeUrl: 'remove',
      removeVerb: 'DELETE',
      autoUpload: false
  },
  template: '<span class=\'file-name-heading\'>Name:</span> <span>#=name#</span><button type=\'button\' class=\'k-upload-action\'></button>',
  validation: {
      allowedExtensions: ["doc", "txt", "docx", "pdf", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "xlsx", "xls"],
      maxFileSize: 20000000, //20mb (in bytes)
  }
}
```

In your specific example, you need to make this dynamic, so you should be able to adjust the values in the configuration object depending on what you've selected in the dropdown. So rather than referencing a static array, reference a variable that you can alter at runtime.

Further documentation:

- https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/configuration/validation#validation.allowedExtensions
- https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/angular